# Why is it important to know the spin of bioinorganic complexes?

Tags: coordination-compounds, metal, spin

During a bioinorganic chemistry course, my teacher gives a lot of importance to spin states of metal ions and how they changes (or not) after the formation of a complex.

For example, when hemoglobin's Fe(II) ion couples with oxygen molecule, it's spin changes from high spin to low. My teacher says that is very important but he doesn't give a reason.

Comment: In short, understanding chemistry -> understand structure -> understand how it carries out its function. In this case, the structure around Fe is very important in understanding the cooperative binding of O2.